# Запуск в режиме программного рендеринга (cinnamon)?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, драйвер, железо, radeon

Сижу под linux mint. При включении получаю алерт в виде **Запуск в режиме программного рендеринга. В настоящее время Cinnamon работает без аппаратного ускорения видео, поэтому может наблюдаться заметный рост нагрузки на процессор**

Посмотрел температуру через `sensors`, через 5-7 минут работы около 60 градусов показывает.

Процессор:

```
Processor Information
Socket Designation: Socket FT1
Type: Central Processor
Family: A-Series
Manufacturer: AMD processor
ID: 01 0F 61 00 FF FB 8B 17
Signature: Family 21, Model 16, Stepping 1
Flags:
    FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)
    VME (Virtual mode extension)
    DE (Debugging extension)
    PSE (Page size extension)
    TSC (Time stamp counter)
    MSR (Model specific registers)
    PAE (Physical address extension)
    MCE (Machine check exception)
    CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)
    APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)
    SEP (Fast system call)
    MTRR (Memory type range registers)
    PGE (Page global enable)
    MCA (Machine check architecture)
    CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)
    PAT (Page attribute table)
    PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)
    CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)
    MMX (MMX technology supported)
    FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)
    SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)
    SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)
    HTT (Multi-threading)
Version: **AMD A10-4655M APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics**  
Voltage: 1.0 V
External Clock: 100 MHz
Max Speed: 2000 MHz
Current Speed: 2000 MHz
Status: Populated, Enabled
Upgrade: None
L1 Cache Handle: 0x0027
L2 Cache Handle: 0x0028
L3 Cache Handle: Not Provided
Serial Number: NotSupport
Asset Tag: FFFF
Part Number: FFFF
Core Count: 4
Core Enabled: 4
Thread Count: 4
Characteristics:
    64-bit capable
```

Полез в менеджер драйверов

```
    Advanced Micro Devices, Inc [AMD/ATI]: Trinity[Radeon HD  7620G]
    Это устройство использует рекомендованный драйвер
xserver-xorg-video-ati(рекомендованный)(свободный)

fglrx


И еще одно устройство

Неизвестно
Это устройство использует альтернативный драйвер

amd64-microcode
```

Боюсь держать компьютер в работе долгое время из-за перегрева. Искать дефолтный драйвер для видеокарты, подскажите что делать?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вместо свободного драйвера поставить пропиетарный